# how to access usercontrol values through scripts

Tags: c#, javascript, user-controls

I have a usercontrol with a datalist which comprises of checkboxes. As I cannot pass usercontrol through script, im trying to form a label with selected values, how can i do this

```
<asp:DataList id="checkedDataList" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px"
            Width="100%" style="OVERFLOW: auto" BackColor="White" Height="150px" CssClass="bodytext">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox id=chkBxItems CssClass="bodytext" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' runat="server" BackColor="White" ToolTip='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'>
                </asp:CheckBox>
                <asp:Label id=lblID Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

this is the usercontrol im using. If i give autopostback='true' to checkbox i'll get the checked values, but returns error from callserver. if no autopostback callserver invokes the serverside methods, but cant get the checked values

```
    currentPageStatus = document.getElementById("lblStatus").innerText;
    var iv='<%= ucchkLst.funcGetcheckedIDString() %>';
    document.getElementById("lblChkdids").innerText = iv;
    CallServer(currentPageStatus,'');
```

if autopostback=true for checkboxes i get iv as i want, but returns error at callserver. If autopostback not set iv is blank and callserver is successful

Answer (score 1):

You can use public property in your User Control and pass selected values

```
public StringBuilder YourValues
{
   get;
   set; 
}
```

If you want get this property just try in your aspx

```
UserControl uc = (UserControl)this.FindControl("yourId");
```

var result = uc.YourValues.ToString();

You can get checkbox value

```
YourValues = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataListItem item in myDataList.Items)
{
   var myCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl ("myCheckBoxId");
   if(myCheckBox.Selected)
   {
     YourValues.Append(myCheckBox.Text);
   }
}
```

Comment: i have the function to get checkbox value, but the script part doesnt seem to work at all.

Comment: by giving autopostback to checkbox im able to get the checked values as string, but returns error when callserver method is invoked

Comment: add runat="server" to all controls, and adjust your code :  var myCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl ("......"); set your good id